# Java-Cucumber tests using spring dependency injection throws NullPointerException when Feature spans Step classes

Tags: java, spring, selenium, dependency-injection, cucumber

I am using a fairly typical Maven architecture, Java-Cucumber, Selenium, with Spring Dependency Injection test system set up to test a dynamic Angular front end website. (Versions in the pom.xml)[ArchitectureWSpringDI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRDLQ.png) It works really well, I can run hundreds of tests easily, but I can't "DRY" out the test steps the way I could with Ruby Watir. One article states that Ruby has a "world" object that Java is lacking, but the Spring used for Dependency Injection is supposed to solve that

I've read a lot of "retaining state" posts, but nothing seems to apply to how this works, and a lot are several versions behind in Cucumber and Spring, though I am still using Java 8. Most of posts for retaining state seem to be between steps in a single file, in a single test.

The main example, which is one of many, is I want to be able to have a steps file with my @Given I login step, and not have to put that step in a hundred other step files.

If I have a feature file like this:

```
Feature: As an account holder I examine account details

  Scenario: View personal summary widget info on details page
    Given Log into "web" on "dev" as "username" with "password" using "chrome"
    When I tap the first account section
    Then I see a list of transactions
```

and match it with a steps file that has all the steps in it like this

```
@SpringBootTest
public class AccountsSteps {

    private final MyAccountsPage page;
    @Autowired
    public AccountsSteps(MyAccountsPage page){
        this.page = page;
    }

    @Given("Log into {string} on {string} as {string} with {string} using {string}")
    public void logIntoOnAsWithUsing(String app, String env, String user, String pass, String browser) {
        page.loadAny(env, app, browser);
        page.sendUsername(user);
        page.sendPassword(pass);
        page.loginButtonClick();
    }

    @When("I tap the first account section")
    public void iTapTheFirstAccountSection() {
        page.waitForListOfElementType(WebElement);
        page.clickFirstAccountLink();
    }

    @Then("I see a list of transactions")
    public void iSeeAListOfTransactions() {
        By selector = By.cssSelector("div.container");
        page.waitForLocateBySelector(selector);
        Assert.assertTrue(page.hasTextOnPage("Account details"));
    }
}
```

Everything works great, but if I have another Feature that uses the same @Given, so the one above and below are exact, so it doesn't create a new step in the new Steps file.

```
Feature: As an account owner I wish to edit my details

  Scenario: My profile loads and verifies the correct member's name
    Given Log into "web" on "dev" as "username" with "password" using "chrome"
    When I use the link in the Self service drop down for My profile
    Then the Contact Details tab loads the proper customer name "Firstname Lastname"
```

Matched to this Step file, notice the lack of a Given step since it's using the one from the other file.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyProfileSteps {

    private final MyProfilePage page;
    @Autowired
    public MyProfileSteps(MyProfilePage page){
        this.page = page;
    }

    @When("I use the link in the Self service drop down for My profile")
    public void iUseTheLinkInTheSelfServiceDropDownForMyProfile() {
        page.clickSelfServiceLink();
        page.clickMyProfileLink();
    }

    @Then("the Contact Details tab loads the proper customer name {string}")
    public void theContactDetailsTabLoadsTheCustomerName(String fullName) {
        System.out.println(page.getCustomerNameFromProfile().getText());
        Assert.assertTrue(page.getCustomerNameFromProfile().getText().contains(fullName));
        page.teardown();
    }
}
```

I finally get to the crux of my problem. Upon switching to a step in a different step file, it throws the exception.

```
When I use the link in the Self service drop down for My profile
      java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:97)
    at projectname.pages.BasePage.waitForClickableThenClickByLocator(BasePage.java:417)
    at projectname.pages.BasePageWeb.clickSelfServiceLink(BasePageWeb.java:858)
    at projectname.steps.MyProfileSteps.iUseTheLinkInTheSelfServiceDropDownForMyProfile(MyProfileSteps.java:39)
    at ✽.I use the link in the drop down for My profile(file:///Users/name/git/project/tests/projectname/src/test/resources/projectname/features/autocomplete/my_profile.feature:10)
```

I've specifically tied them all together so a test only calls one new Selenium Instance per test, and it is definitely not opening a new browser window, it just crashes and closes.

```
public interface WebDriverInterface {

    WebDriver getDriver();
    WebDriver getDriverFire();
    void shutdownDriver();
    WebDriver stopOrphanSession();
}
```

And there are several profiles that will run different configurations, but my main local testing WebDriverInterface looks like this.

```
@Profile("local")
@Primary
@Component
public class DesktopLocalBrowsers implements WebDriverInterface {

    @Value("${browser.desktop.width}")
    private int desktopWidth;

    @Value("${browser.desktop.height}")
    private int desktopHeight;

    @Value("${webdriver.chrome.mac.driver}")
    private String chromedriverLocation;

    @Value("${webdriver.gecko.mac.driver}")
    private String firefoxdriverLocation;

    public WebDriver local;
    public WebDriver local2;

    public DesktopLocalBrowsers() {
    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverLocation);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=" + desktopWidth + "," + desktopHeight);
        local = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        return local;
    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver getDriverFire() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", firefoxdriverLocation);
        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.FATAL);
        firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
        local2 = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        return local2;
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownDriver() {
        try{
            local.quit();
        }catch (NullPointerException npe){
            local2.quit();
        }
    }


    public WebDriver stopOrphanSession(){
        try{
            if(local != null){
                return local;
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException npe){
            System.out.println("All Drivers Closed");
        }
        return local2;
    }
}
```

I have fairly standard Runners. I've tried several variations of the Cucumber Runner, moved around into different directories, using glue and extraglue configurations, but either nothing changes, or I break it completely. Here is the one that is working now.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/projectname/features/",
        glue = "backbase",
//        extraGlue = "common",   // glue and extraGlue cannot be used together
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "summary",
                "de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports:target/cucumber",
        })
public class RunCucumberTest {

}
```

and my Spring Runner

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class SpringContextRunner {
}
```

And the out of the box Application page for reference.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And just in case someone finds it useful to brainstorming or diagnosing, my page objects start with the BasePage, which has become far too enormous since it contains all the common methods, but looks something like this.

```
public abstract class BasePageWeb {
    
    @Value("${projectname.retail.dev}")
    private String devUrl;
    @Value("${projectname.retail.sit}")
    private String sitUrl;
    @Value("${projectname.retail.uat}")
    private String uatUrl;

    protected WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;

    protected final WebDriverInterface webDriverInterface;

    public BasePageWeb(WebDriverInterface webDriverInterface) {
        this.webDriverInterface = webDriverInterface;
    }

    // env choices: lcl, dev, sit, uat -> app choices: web, id, emp, cxm -> browser choices: chrome, fire
    public void loadAny(String env, String app, String browser) {

        if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
            driver = this.webDriverInterface.getDriver();
        } else if (browser.equals("fire")) {
            driver = this.webDriverInterface.getDriverFire();
        }

        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

        String url = "";
        String title = "";
        switch (app) {
            case "web":
                switch (env) {
                    case "dev":
                        url = devUrl;
                        title = "Log in to Project Name";
                        break;
                    case "sit":
                        url = sitUrl;
                        title = "Log in to Project Name";
                        break;
                    case "uat":
                        url = uatUrl;
                        title = "Log in to Project Name";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("There were no matches to your login choices.");
        }
        driver.get(url);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(title));
    }
}
```

And then when I have specific topics where I can create methods that will apply only to that sub area, I extend out the base page, and I inject the sub page into the Steps pages.

```
@Component
public class MyAccountsPage extends BasePageWeb {


    public MyAccountsPage(WebDriverInterface webDriverInterface) {
        super(webDriverInterface);
    }

    // Find the Product Title Elements, Convert to Strings, and put them all in a simple List.

    public List<String> getAccountInfoTitles(){
        List<WebElement> accountInfoTitlesElements =
                driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div > .bb-account-info__title"));
        return accountInfoTitlesElements.stream()
                                        .map(WebElement::getText)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong, or make suggestions for investigation, I would appreciate it. I know there have been some major cucumber changes after 6.6.0 for how the framework scans for annotations and such, but I haven't been able to determine if that is related or not.

For reference. The pom.xml with all the versions and included dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>java-cucumber-generic</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-cucumber-generic-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.6.0</cucumber.version>
        <junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <port>8358</port>
        <cucumber.reporting.version>5.3.1</cucumber.reporting.version>
        <cucumber.reporting.config.file>automation-web/src/test/resources/projectname/cucumber-reporting.properties</cucumber.reporting.config.file>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <h2database.version>1.4.200</h2database.version>
        <appium.java.client.version>7.3.0</appium.java.client.version>
        <guava.version>29.0-jre</guava.version>
        <reporting-plugin.version>4.0.83</reporting-plugin.version>
        <commons-text.version>1.9</commons-text.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.8.0</commons-io.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added beyond original archetype -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To make Wait Until work -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cucumber Reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.monochromata.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>reporting-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${reporting-plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- For dependency injection https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/#dependency-injection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2database.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- To generate getters, setters, equals, hascode, toString methods -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java client, wrapped by Appium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${appium.java.client.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-text.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Added beyond original archetype -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure that both AccountsSteps and MyProfileSteps are in the same folder backbase so cucumber can find both of them?

Comment: Yes, I am very methodical with my files. All pages are in one, all steps are in another. My features are spread between multiple folders, but Cucumber isn't having in trouble with them. I'm pretty sure Mr. Korstanje nailed the problem, but I've just created a new branch to refactor with. I will soon know for certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two page classes `MyAccountsPage` and `MyProfilePage`. While both extend `BasePageWeb` and thus any instances of the `MyAccountsPage` and `MyProfilePage` are are also instances `BasePageWeb` they are not the same instance!

This can be quite confusing initially because usually there is only a single instance of each class and we treat the instance and the class as if they were the same thing. Rather think of the class as a template from which many instances can be made.

Now if you attach the debugger and inspect the pages before they are used you should see something like this:

```
MyAccountsPage@1001
 - WebDriver driver = null  <--- field inherited from BasePageWeb
 - other fields

MyProfilePage@1002 <--- different memory address, so different instance!
 - WebDriver driver = null   <--- field inherited from BasePageWeb 
 - other fields
```

So when you setup the `WebDriver` using the steps in `AccountsSteps`, the `WebDriver is setup in` MyProfilePage`but not`MyProfilePage`.

```
MyAccountsPage@1001
 - WebDriver driver = Webdriver@1003  <-- This one was set.
 - other fields

MyProfilePage@1002
 - WebDriver driver = null   <--- This one is still null.
 - other fields
```

So when you try use the `ProfileSteps` that try to use `MyProfilePage` you end up with an null pointer exception because the instance of the `WebDriver` in `MyProfilePage` was never setup.

There are a few solutions here, but they all come down to keeping the webdriver in a single instance by making `BasePageWeb` a component and using composition instead of inheritance.

```java
@Component
@ScenarioScope
public class BasePageWeb {
 ...
}
```

```java
public class AccountsSteps {

    private final BasePageWeb basePageWeb;
    private final MyAccountsPage page;

    @Autowired
    public AccountsSteps(BasePageWeb basePageWeb, MyAccountsPage page){
        this.basePageWeb = basePageWeb;
        this.page = page;
    }

    @Given("Log into {string} on {string} as {string} with {string} using {string}")
    public void logIntoOnAsWithUsing(String app, String env, String user, String pass, String browser) {
        basePageWeb.loadAny(env, app, browser);
        page.sendUsername(user);
        page.sendPassword(pass);
        page.loginButtonClick();
    }
    ....
```

```java
@Component
@ScenarioScope
public class MyAccountsPage {
    private final BasePageWeb basePageWeb;

    public MyAccountsPage(BasePageWeb basePageWeb) {
        this.basePageWeb = basePageWeb;
    }
    ...
}
```

```java
@Component
@ScenarioScope
public class MyProfilePage {
    private final BasePageWeb basePageWeb;

    public MyProfilePage(BasePageWeb basePageWeb) {
        this.basePageWeb = basePageWeb;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something fundamental. Not having arrived in this field through a traditional comp sci route, I wound up having to read up on Inheritance vs. Composition, and on about the 4th read through of your answer, I think I'm seeing it finally.

My understanding here is every page becomes an independent Component, then I can Autowire any page I need into the constructor for the steps I'm using, aka "Compose" my Steps.

To clarify from your point above, only the BasePageWeb Component would then get assigned a WebDriver, yes?

BasePageWeb@1001
 - WebDriver driver = null

Comment: Sounds about right. Keep in mind that the component annotation ensures that there is a single instance of the annoyated in the spring application context (the dependency injection container) this need not be true in all circumstances.

Comment: And you are welcome! Figured you didn't go the formal route. Might also be good to play with inheritance and composition in plain java so you can create multiple instances and try to experience the differences. It will help if you draw objects and their references to each other.

Comment: Taking out the BasePageWeb inheritance and setting everything up as Components has fixed all my Spring wiring issues with Cucumber. For many years I've been very hesitant to ask questions here because of many snarky replies I've seen, but this was completely worth the effort. Your suggested refactor works like magic! Thank You for taking the time to explain what was going wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Okay. Don't forget the `@ScenarioScope` annotation to avoid sharing state between scenarios. I forgot to add that. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/spring#sharing-state

Comment: Oh, well I can't forget it since this is the first I've seen it. :P Thank You for that. I've added some comments to the appropriate areas to remind myself. It looks very useful in the right circumstances.